# Synchronizing clients in javascript without my own backend

Tags: javascript, html

**Warning: sound** (not loud, and volume is set to 0.5 in the code)
My goal here is to get anyone who enters the webpage synchronized as well as possible.

Say there's some global clock. Since Javascript's `Date.now()` is based on the device's clock, relying on it isn't good enough.

So, I'm using `worldtimeapi` which returns the time down to the milliseconds to get `diff` so that, ideally, `Date.now() + diff` would evaluate, on any device, to the same value at any given moment. `diff` is essentially supposed to correct the device's deviation from some global clock.

I can hear the difference when running this on my phone vs. on my laptop, but ultimately I'm not sure how I could possibly tell if this is the best I can expect or if there's a difference that can be reduced with better code and without setting up my own backend NTP.

```js
var duration = 27193;
var diff=1000;
var handle = null;
var best_delay = 1000;
var sound = document.getElementById("sound");
var timebox = document.getElementById("time_set");
var start = document.getElementById("start");
sound.volume = 0.5;
sound.onended = (event) => {
    play();
}
function play()
{
  sound.currentTime = ((Date.now() - diff) % duration)/1000;
  sound.play()
}

function gettime() {

  console.log("getting time");
  try {
    clearInterval(handle);
  }
  catch (error) {}
  var start = new Date();
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.worldtimeapi.org/api/Asia/Macau",true);
  xhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      let response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
      let time_at = new Date(response.datetime);
      let now = Date.now();
      let delay = now - start;
      let new_diff = now - time_at-delay/2;
      if (delay < best_delay)
      {
        best_delay = delay;
        diff = new_diff;
        console.log(diff)

      }
      timebox.innerHTML += diff.toString() + "," + delay;
      timebox.innerHTML+="\n";
      play();
    }
  }
  xhttp.send(null);
}
start.onclick = function () {
  gettime();
}
```

```html
<audio id="sound" src="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls preload="auto"></audio>

<textarea id="time_set"></textarea>
<br>
<button id="start">
START
</button>
```

Comment: You'll need to account for different request speeds. You can measure round trip time to the time server over multiple requests and use the medium. Synchronizing clocks isn't easy, and there's lots of algorithms for it out there that you can Google, all with different weaknesses.